# Adding a New Column to an Empty NumPy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to add a new column to an empty NumPy array and am facing some troubles. I've looked at a lot of other questions, but for some reason they don't seem to be helping me solve the problem I'm facing, so I decided to ask my own question.

I have an empty NumPy array such that:

```
array1 = np.array([])
```

Let's say I have data that is of shape `(100, 100)`, and want to append each column to `array1` one by one. However, if I do for example:

```
array1 = np.append(array1, some_data[:, 0])
array1 = np.append(array1, some_data[:, 1])
```

I noticed that I won't be getting a `(100, 2)` matrix, but a `(200,)` array. So I tried to specify the `axis` as

```
array1 = np.append(array1, some_data[:, 0], axis=1)
```

which produces a `AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1.`

Next I tried to use the `np.c_[]` method:

```
array1 = np.c_[array1, somedata[:, 0]]
```

which gives me a `ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly.`

Is there any way that I would be able to add columns to the NumPy array sequentially?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I learned that my initial question didn't contain enough information for others to offer help, and made this update to make up for the initial mistake.

My big objective is to make a program that selects features in a "greedy fashion." Basically, I'm trying to take the design matrix `some_data`, which is a `(100, 100)` matrix containing floating point numbers as entries, and fitting a linear regression model with an increasing number of features until I find the best set of features.

For example, since I have a total of 100 features, the first round would fit the model on each 100, select the best one and store it, then continue with the remaining 99.

That's what I'm trying to do in my head, but I got stuck from the beginning with the problem I mentioned.

Comment: Could you provide at least a reduced version of what your variable `some_data` contains?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll update my question with the information.

Comment: `array([])` is not the equivalent of list `[]` when it comes concatenation. And `np.append` doesn't work like list append.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You start with a (0,) array and (n,) shaped one:

```
In [482]: arr1 = np.array([])
In [483]: arr1.shape
Out[483]: (0,)
In [484]: arr2 = np.array([1,2,3])
In [485]: arr2.shape
Out[485]: (3,)
```

`np.append` uses `concatenate` (but with some funny business when axis is not provided):

```
In [486]: np.append(arr1, arr2)
Out[486]: array([1., 2., 3.])
In [487]: np.append(arr1, arr2,axis=0)    
Out[487]: array([1., 2., 3.])
In [489]: np.concatenate([arr1, arr2])
Out[489]: array([1., 2., 3.])
```

And trying axis=1

```
In [488]: np.append(arr1, arr2,axis=1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AxisError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-488-457b8657453e> in <module>()
----> 1 np.append(arr1, arr2,axis=1)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in append(arr, values, axis)
   4526         values = ravel(values)
   4527         axis = arr.ndim-1
-> 4528     return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)

AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

Look at the whole message - the error occurs in the `concatenate` step.  You can't concatenate 1d arrays along `axis=1`.

Using `np.append` or even `np.concatenate` iteratively is slow (it creates a new array each time), and hard to initialize correctly.  It is a poor substitute for the widely use list `append-to-empty-list` recipe.

`np.c_` is also just a cover function for `concatenate`.

There isn't just one `empty` array.  `np.array([[]])` and `np.array([[[]]])` also have 0 elements.

If you want to add a column to an array, you need to start with a 2d array, and the column also needs to be 2d.

Here's an example of a proper concatenation of 2 2d arrays:

```
In [490]: np.concatenate([ np.zeros((3,0),int), np.arange(3)[:,None]], axis=1)
Out[490]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])
```

`column_stack` is another cover function for `concatenate` that makes sure the inputs are 2d.  But even with that getting an initial 'empty' array is tricky.

```
In [492]: np.column_stack([np.zeros(3,int), np.arange(3)])
Out[492]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2]])
In [493]: np.column_stack([np.zeros((3,0),int), np.arange(3)])
Out[493]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])
```

`np.c_` is a lot like `column_stack`, though implemented in a different way:

```
In [496]: np.c_[np.zeros(3,int), np.arange(3)]
Out[496]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2]])
```

The basic message is, that when using `np.concatenate` you need to pay attention to dimensions.  Its variants allow you to fudge things a bit, but you really need to understand that fudging to get things right, especially when starting from this poorly defined idea of a 'empty' array.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use concatenate method and do it like this:

```
# Some stuff
alldata = None
....
array1 = np.random.random((100,1))
if alldata is None: alldata = array1
...
array2 = np.random.random((100,1))

alldata = np.concatenate((alldata,array2),axis=1)
```

In case, you are working with vectors:

```
alldata = None
....
array1 = np.random.random((100,))
if alldata is None: alldata = array1[:,np.newaxis]
...
array2 = np.random.random((100,))

alldata = np.concatenate((alldata,array2[:,np.newaxis]),axis=1)
```